# How to build only updated modules in bamboo in 2022

Tags: maven, module, continuous-integration, bamboo

Using Bamboo version 7.1.3.

**Context:**

I've just starting working with bamboo / maven projects coming from jenkins / ant+ivy so bear with me. I have no previous experience with maven but it should not be relevant to what I am trying to achieve unless I am missing fundamentals.

We've got one repository per technology, e.g

```
  JAVA_REPO
    ---| JavaProject1
    ---| JavaProject2
    ...
    ---| JavaProjectN. 
    
  REPORTS_REPO
    ---| ReportProject1
    ---| ReportProject2
    ...
    ---| ReportProjectN
```

**GOAL:**

As a devOps consultant, I would like bamboo (using java-specs) to **only** build JavaProject3 if a change is detected. Also, if JavaProject4 have a dependency on JavaProject3, then trigger that build also but nothing else.

**Jenkins and ant+ivy:**

In the old world, I would have

```
 JAVA_REPO
    ---| JavaProject1
    -------| ivy.xml
    -------| build.xml
    ---| JavaProject2
    -------| ivy.xml
    -------| build.xml
    ...
    ---| JavaProjectN.
    -------| ivy.xml
    -------| build.xml
```

I would then install an ivy plugin in JENKINS and create an Ivy Project. Jenkins would then scan the whole repository and create 'Modules' based on the ivy.xml it founds. Since each module would have the same build.xml structure and targets, you specify to call the publish or whatever target you want. Jenkins would then start only the modules that were changed as part of a commit and if there were other projects depending on that module, those would be queued as well. Everything kind of out of the box.

**Bamboo / Maven:**

I am struggling to find anything like the above, even if I have to implement it myself. I've been doing research but not sure if I am missing fundamentals as I don't think I am the first one having this issue / problem.

**What I have:**

```
 JAVA_REPO
    pom.xml (packaging pom)
    ---| JavaSpecProject
    -------|pom.xml
    ---| JavaProject1
    -------| pom.xml
    ---| JavaProject2
    -------| pom.xml
    ...
    ---| JavaProjectN.
    -------| pom.xml
```

At the moment, I have only found one option which is to create as many repository connections as modules I have and then ask bamboo to only check on changed files 'patterns' etc. I find that solution ugly.

I am thinking that using java specs I may be able to write a bunch of code to do what I am trying to do but I also find that a little bit ugly.

How are you guys are doing this?

Comment: Are the projects javaspecproject, javaproject1 within a single git repo? Also do you use a multi module build which looks like this (packaging: pom) ... do they have dependencies on each other ? If so build from root via `mvn package` or `mvn deploy` if necessary...

Comment: Yes but that will basically do a whole build. If I have 50 projects, I don't want to create 50 new artifacts when only one project needed building (which is currently what is happening in my CI environment using bamboo). @khmarbaise

Comment: Are those 50 projects related with dependencies between each other or are those project independent?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have one project where common code is shared and consumed by other projects however. So 49 projects will have a dependency in 1 project. However I actually don't care (for now) about triggering dependencies automatically. I just need to only build and publish artifacts for the updated modules only. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I just found your project @khmarbaise -> incremental-module-builder. This, I think, is what I am looking for. Would you agree?

Answer (score 0):

> create as many repository connections as modules I have and then ask bamboo to only check on changed files 'patterns'

This is the only way: separate plan per maven project. Add Maven Dependencies Processor tasks and the plans will build themselves after each other according to their dependencies.

> incremental-module-builder

This requires shared state and doesn't work for our company since we use ephemeral agents and clean working directories.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to write a bash script comparing the HEAD vs HEAD^ and then see which module have changed and issue a
 mvn clean -pl $module install / deploy.

Comment: That won't work when I merge two commits with one PR.

Comment: thanks - I haven't actually tested that scenario. Do you have an idea then how to accomplish it when you have 2 or more commits with one PR? Maybe diffing to the latest tag instead? Having bamboo tag the branch when it merges?

Comment: Bamboo won't tag automatically. The only reliable way would be to query the Bamboo API for the latest green build from the current branch and take its git rev against which you can then do your diff-ing. IMHO, this becomes unnecessarily overcomplicated and prone to errors/edge cases compared to the plan-per-project-with-patterns-matching setup.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/maven-build-cache/  should work in theory. I haven't tested this approach in practice.

Comment: I agree - but I can't get my head around creating 20+ repository connections just to map the projects on each when in Jenkins all it took is one ivy / maven plugin and an option to enable 'modules'. So I guess I am re-inventing the wheel somehow. Probably you are right though.

Comment: "creating 20+ repository connections" totally agree that's not feasible considering the fact that Bamboo specs still don't support creating (linked) repos. I'd go with Jenkins if that worked fine and stay away from Bamboo, if I were you. One more thing: are you 100% sure Jenkins really builds only modified projects?

Comment: yes - I've done it several times in my previous contracts. I work in a niche area within where most of the build/deployment work is done via ant. So I chose ivy to implement dependency management. Jenkin's got an ivy plugin and basically scans all ivy.xml and builds everything once and then thereafter only triggers the modules that changed on the commit. Can't use jenkins now though - they've already chosen bamboo.